# How do I remotely connect over TCP to a SQL Server 2008 instance (firewall is off, TCP is enabled)?

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance from another machine using the TCP protocol over port 1433.

On the server side:

- SQL Server is running.
- SQL Server has had its "Allow remote connections to this server"
  checkbox checked.
- SQL Server has the TCP protocol enabled.
- At least one of the IP addresses in the list of IP addresses that SQL
  Server claims to be listening on is the correct one.  None of the
  items in this list are **Enabled**, but that is not anything that I
  have touched.  All are **Active**.  All have their port set to 1433
  (I never touched it).  I have also set all of them to **Enabled** at various points; this made no difference.  I have not been able to track down any documentation on why both an active status and an enabled status need to be maintained.
- TCP dynamic ports is set to blank (I never touched it) for all IP
  addresses.  As I understand it, this is what you want to do for connections that should specify the TCP port explicitly in their connection information (which is what I want).
- TCP port is set to 1433 for all IP addresses, including IPAll.
- The firewall is off.
- SQL Server authentication is set to SQL Server Authentication
  (followed by Windows Authentication).

I am able to ping the box remotely.

The symptoms of not being able to connect are basically my client (a JDBC client) hangs.  The URL is analogous to this: `jdbc:sqlserver://my.host.here:1433;databaseName=frob` and I specify a valid user and password (and in any event do not get a login/security error).

The URL is valid and well-formed.

I can telnet to port 1433 on the box without a connection refusal error so the port is open.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is: it's a regression in the JDK, version 1.6.0 update 29 (you know, the version that is current on the Mac).  See this: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7105007